# Setting Long TTL on Redisson -- DragonFlyDB

Tags: redis, redisson

I'm trying to set large TTL (10+ days) for key-value on Redisson.

I noctied that Redisson convert that TTL to milliseconds and execute command on Redis(DragonFlyDB).

```
org.redisson.client.RedisException: ERR value is not an integer or out of range. channel: [id: 0xfa05de9e, L:/127.0.0.1:32812 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:32773] command: (PSETEX), promise: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@67330d28[Not completed], params: [hello, 864000000, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 8, cap: 256)]
```

`864000000` is not larger then maximum `Integer`

DragonFly(https://github.com/dragonflydb/dragonfly)
Is there a way to archieve this ?

---

```
  override fun cacheString(key: String, value: String, ttl: Duration): RFuture<Void> {
       val result = redisClient.getBucket<String>(key).setAsync(value, ttl.seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       return result
}

val failResult = cacheMangerService.cacheString("hello", "world", Duration.ofDays(10)) // throw Exception

val succesResult = cacheMangerService.cacheString("hello", "world", Duration.ofDays(3)) // Successful
```

Edited: I switch DragonFlyDB to RedisCluster --> And 864000000 work. So it seem like it only apply to DragonFlyDB.

Solved: For some reason it only happened when set TTL in setAsync but not set TTL manually with expire(). So I workaround by change set TTL with expire()

Thanks you for reading

Comment: Can you share the code where you set the key?

Comment: @duckoak I have attach my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: For some reason it only happened when set TTL in setAsync but not set TTL manually with expire() --> expire() use a eval srcipt.
So I workaround by change set TTL with expire()

```
val bucket = getBucket(buildKey(key))
bucket.setAsync(value).handleAsync { _, throwable ->
  if (throwable != null) {
    logger.error("Error in caching value: ", throwable)
  } else {
    bucket.expireAsync(ttl).handleAsync { rs, throwable ->
      if (throwable != null || !rs) {
        // If expire error then remove the value
        logger.error("Error in set expire for value: ", throwable)
        bucket.delete()
      }
    }
  }
}
```